# Extension of type 'BintrayExtension' does not exist

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, bintray, maven-publish

My project `build.gradle`:

```
...
plugins {
    id "maven-publish"
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.8.5"
}
```

My library module `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'com.android.lint'
...
if (project.rootProject.file('local.properties').exists()) {
    apply from: rootProject.file('deploy-bintray.gradle.kts')
}
```

My library module `deploy-bintray.gradle.kts`:

```
import com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayExtension

apply(plugin = "maven-publish")
apply(plugin = "com.jfrog.bintray")

configure<BintrayExtension> {...}
configure<PublishingExtension> {...}
```

And this is the error I get from `gradle assemble`:

> Extension of type 'BintrayExtension' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [ExtraPropertiesExtension,
>   KotlinJvmProjectExtension, KotlinTestsRegistry,
>   DefaultArtifactPublicationSet, ReportingExtension, SourceSetContainer,
>   JavaPluginExtension, JavaInstallationRegistry, LintOptions,
>   PublishingExtension, BintrayExtension]

I've added:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2")
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5")
    }
}
```

But I get the same output... If I open `BintrayExtension.groovy` the package name `com.jfrog.bintray.gradle` has this warning:

> Package name mismatch. Actual: 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle', expected:
>   ''

and the class:

> Class 'BintrayExtension' already exists in 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle'

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is replacing:

```
id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.8.5"
```

with:

```
plugins.apply(BintrayPlugin::class.java)
```

Many thanks to **Tom Eyckmans** for [pointing](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/301#issuecomment-641612163) this out.